# No implicit conversion of Hash into String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

When someone types `"!disconnect"`, I want the bot to disconnect, using the response `"PART ##{CHANNEL}"`.

The snippet below is not the full code, but there are `end` statements and everything.

```
CHANNEL = "SomeChannelHere"
prefix = "!"
message = "!disconnect"

commands = [
    "disconnect" => "PART ##{CHANNEL}"]

commands.each do |command|
    if message.include?(prefix + command)
        response = commands[command]
```

How do I get the response?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get multiple syntax errors when trying to verify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `commands` is currently an array of hashes:

```
commands = ["disconnect" => "PART ##{CHANNEL}"]
#=> [{"disconnect"=>"PART #SomeChannelHere"}]
```

You have to use `{ ... }` instead of `[ ... ]`:

```
commands = {"disconnect" => "PART ##{CHANNEL}"}
#=> {"disconnect"=>"PART #SomeChannelHere"}
```

Furthermore, the `each` block expects two arguments (key and value):

```
commands.each do |command, response|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the key of the hash:

```
commands.each do |command|
 p command["disconnect"]
 p command.has_key?("disconnect")
end
```